# Получение результата выполнения при выборе файла

Tags: android, java

Я запускаю активити с выбором файла таким кодом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setType("*/*"); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); 
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Есть ли какая-то возможность, чтобы получить результат выполнения этой активити, не используя связку методов `startActivityForResult` и `onActivityResult`? Потому что предполагается, что код может вызываться из разных активити. Так что перегружать метод `onActivityResult` у какой-то конкретной активити никак не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что при таком способе запуска `Activity` (как вы описали) вы не можете знать заранее какой `Activity` будет запущен. Будет запущен довольно сложный механизм поиска подходящего активити и если не будет дефолтного то юзеру будет предъявлен их список откуда он сможет рученьками выбрать нужный.

Так что окромя как `onActivityResult` вариантов нет. Если даже код будет запускаться из многих `Activity` ничто не мешает вам сделать единый родительский класс и разместить `onActivityResult` там - так что и код будет один и не надо будет изобретать велосипед. ООП рулит!

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как влияет то, что может быть запущен какой угодно активити на то, что я не могу получить результат откуда-либо, кроме активити :( Насчет родительского класса - это и так понятно. Просто предполагалось, что запуск диалога происходит из кода, который вообще не знает про активити. А так, придется делать какие-нибудь кривые подпорки.